# ¿Como redondear un float a integer (hacia arriba)?

Tags: javascript, float, integer

Tengo una operación que me devuelve un float por ejemplo `6.3` y necesito que me lo redondee hacia `7`
He probado con `Math.round(6.3)` pero cuando el decimal es menor de 0.5 redondea hacia abajo y cuando es mayor redondea  hacia arriba y necesito que siempre lo haga hacia arriba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para redondear hacia arriba usa `Math.ceil`:

```js
let numero= 6.345;


let entero = Math.ceil(numero);

console.log(entero)
```

[Fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/ceil)